# How to know what version of ICU comes with an OS?

Tags: unicode, icu

They say [here](http://cldr.unicode.org/#TOC-Who-uses-CLDR-) that ICU is used on many platforms. But I can't find what version comes with OS X and Windows. In Linux I suppose a package-manager would tell me.

UPDATE: Changed CLDR to ICU

Comment: That's not [the way it works](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/04/11/10516280.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, but I know how it works. I didn't mean 'delivered' by the word 'comes'. I just wanna know what version of CLDR is used by particular version of particular OS thus know what bugs/mistranlations there are to be aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether platforms come bundled with ICU. For sure, Windows does not. Unix-based platforms might. For one, [apparently OS X comes bundled](http://blog.lukhnos.org/post/6441462604/using-os-xs-built-in-icu-library-in-your-own-project) with some version of it.

If the platform delivers a full bundle of ICU you can test the version of ICU using the command:

```
$ uconv -V
```

Which will print the version. The latest version is 54.1, it looks like this:

```
uconv v2.1  ICU 54.1
```

In addition, if your platform has Qt installed, it is possible it has been compiled with ICU support, but this is not a necessity.

If you want to use ICU, you're probably better off shipping it with your product as opposed to rely on what is on someone's system. ICU has a fairly regular update cycle, chances are that pre-installed ICU libraries are out of date.

Comment: Windows now does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu-

Comment: @tricasse Apparently since Windows 10 Creator's Update, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Completing @Abel's answer, on macOS the complete command to extract the ICU version is:

```
$(brew --prefix)/opt/icu4c/bin/uconv --version | sed -ne 's/uconv v.* ICU \([0-9][0-9.]*\)/\1/p'
```

This produces e.g. `72.1` as of today (2022-01-21).

On Ubuntu, `uconv` is in the `PATH` if installed, so this is simply:

```
uconv --version | sed -ne 's/uconv v.* ICU \([0-9][0-9.]*\)/\1/p'
```